# Is it possible to send a message from a Content Script to a Background Page using chrome.tabs.sendmessage?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have found plenty of examples and documentation on sending a message from a background page to a content script, but am unable to find a way to send a message from a content script to a background page.

The reason for this is that I want to use `chrome.downloader.download`, e.g.

```
chrome.downloads.download({
        "url": randomImageForSpotCheck
    }, function () {...
       spotcheck(randomImage);
});
```

Comment: I believe the syntax is the same for sending messages from any script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First google search brings up:

> Sending a request from a content script looks like this:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {  
  console.log(response.farewell);  
});
```

[(here)](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging)

Into your background script you should have a bit of code listening for such a message:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (sender.tab) {
        // is from content script
        // access stuff like:
        //   request.horseradish
        sendResponse({});
    }
});
```

and your content script can send the message:

```
//                          vv put whatever data you want here
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({horseradish: true}, function(response) {  
  // this is a callback function to execute,
  // response is the object sent by your sendResponse({});
  //                                     this one     ^^
});
```

Comment: Thanks, what exactly did you google out of curiosity?

Comment: [this](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=chrome%20send%20message%20from%20content%20script%20to%20background%20page) - it's the first result.

Comment: So I've implemented it like you described. The callback function on sendmessage is being called (I have a console.log in there to notify me), but somehow, the code in the addlistener in background page isn't getting executed.

Comment: Just figured it out. I'd never used a background script before, I didn't realize that you had to debug it from clicking on the link in the extensions window.